# Why 1 + + + 1 evaluates to 2 in php?

Tags: php, math, operators, addition, signed

Can anyone please explain why this code prints `2`?

```
$var = 1 + + + 1;
echo $var;
```

Comment: `$var = 1 + (+ (+1))` Those `+` (except the first one) are treated like unary operators.

Comment: Were you expecting something funky with that funky code?

Comment: What result do you expect? What result do you actually get? What the actual result do you find confusing? Please tell us that *in the body* of the question, and keep the title as a short summary.

Comment: I was excepting an error

Answer (score 2):

Reference the [arithmetic operators page in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).

If php has two entities to perform arithmetic/mathematics on, it will prioritize that action rather than identity/negation.  The `+` and `-` symbol(s) will be treated as identity/negation operators when a mathematical operation is already determined between two entities or when there is only one entity.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZKodt))

```
$var4 = 0 - - 4;        // zero minus negated 4
var_export($var4);

echo "\n";
$var5 = - 5;              // negated 5
var_export($var5);

echo "\n";
$var6 = - - 6;            // negated negated 6
var_export($var6);

echo "\n";
$var7 = - - - 7;           // negated negated negated 7
var_export($var7);

echo "\n";
$var8 = - - - - 8;        // negated negated negated negated 8
var_export($var8);
```

Output:

```
4
-5
6
-7
8
```

The non-plus/non-minus operators -- namely: `*`, `/`, `%`, and `**` -- have just one interpretation and so cause a parse error when a prior mathematical operation is already determined.

Dangling right side arithmetic operators cannot be used as add, subtract, identity, negation, etc. and so cause a parse error. E.g `8 - -`  https://3v4l.org/qr2D8

Furthermore...

```
echo 1 + - 2;     // -1  (1 plus neg 2)
echo "\n";
echo 1 - + 2;     // -1  (1 minus pos 2)
echo "\n";
echo 1 + - - 3;   //  4  (1 plus neg neg 3)
echo "\n";
echo 1 - + + 3;   // -2  (1 minus pos pos 3)
echo "\n";
echo 1 - - - 3;   // -2  (1 minus neg neg 3)
echo "\n";
echo 1 + + + 3;   //  4  (1 plus pos pos 3)
echo "\n";
echo 1 + + - - 4; //  5  (1 plus pos neg neg 4)
echo "\n";
echo 1 - - + + 4; //  5  (1 minus neg pos pos 4)
echo "\n";
echo 1 - - - - 4; //  5  (1 minus neg neg neg 4)
echo "\n";
//echo 1 - - * + 4;  // parse error
//echo "\n";
```

Comment: How about this: `$var = - - 10; echo $var;` Results in 10.  Where be those zeros?

Comment: Right you are.  Actually researched and completely rewrote answer.

Comment: 'Two things to add/subtract', is a little ambiguous.

Comment: I believe this part is pretty straight forward, but it all goes pear-shaped when incrementers and decrementers are introduced.   I wanted to post a link to a page that I once commented on regarding expressions like `++$x++$y` or something like that but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Yes, I am certainly dumbing it down.

Comment: I am happy to learn from you if you find something cool.  Though this sort of expression is not really something that will be beneficial in my career, knowledge is knowledge is good.

Comment: I suppose some details about operator precedence would be relevant, but where do I draw the line?  I don't want to deviate too far from the question.

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca, nailed it.  My confusion was with spacing and unary operators.  But spacing of course is fine e.g.  `! $a`.  They are known as the unary minus(negation) and plus operators.  Unary plus was a _late_ addition to C (in ANSI C).

Answer (score 0):

This is basic math. What you are calculating is basically just

```
1 + (++1)
```

and the plus-signs (not the plus-operators) are optional. So it's just

```
1 + (1)
```

which is 2.

---

If you did `1 + + - 1` the result would be 0, because you are calculating

```
1 + (+-1)
```

and + and - can be shortened to just -

so you are calculating

```
1 + (-1)
```

or just

```
1 - 1
```

---

## Reference

As you can see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) the `+` sign can have two different meanings. The first is "identity" and the second is "addition".

```
Arithmetic Operators

Example            Name            Result
+$a                Identity     Conversion of $a to int or float as appropriate.
-$a                Negation     Opposite of $a.
$a + $b            Addition        Sum of $a and $b.
```

That means

```
1 + + + 1
^ ^ ^ ^ ^
| | | | `- int
| | | `- identity operator
| | `- identity operator
| `- addition operator
`- int
```

Comment: Basic math doesn't always translate to programming.  Think `X = X + 1`.

Comment: @Progrock but in this case it does.

Comment: This is just an assumption, unless you can reference.

Comment: @Progrock I've added the fine reference for you

Comment: Identity is a little misleading as coercion can occur.  Probably better to refer as unary plus.